# When used django_tables2, it told me TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.people),
]
```

## views.py

```
def people(request):

    return render(request, 'people.html', {'people': models.Person.objects.all()})
```

## models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):

    name = CharField(verbose_name="full name", max_length=10)
```

## people.html

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load static %}

{% render_table people %}
```

When I run it, it told me `TemplateDoesNotExist at /django_tables2/table.html`, I don't understand why.

Comment: The full error message should give more information, including where Django searched for the template. It would be useful to see your `TEMPLATES` setting as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that `django_tables2` is included in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Then, make sure that you have `APP_DIRS` set to `True` in your `TEMPLATES` setting.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [...],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
    },
]
```

Comment: TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

Comment: Make sure that `django_tables2` is included in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions. As I suggested before, the full error message might show want the problem is (please edit your original question instead of pasting code in the comments).

Comment: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
django_tables2/table.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: 
django_tables2/table.html
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 25

Comment: In template C:\Users\XJ\Desktop\123\untitled\templates\people.html, error at line 10

Comment: 1 {# tutorial/templates/people.html #}
2 {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
3 {% load static %}
4 <!doctype html>
5 <html>
6     <head>
7         <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css' %}" />
8     </head>
9     <body>
10         {% render_table people %}
11     </body>
12 </html>

Comment: As I said, please don't post code in the comments. Edit your original question.

Comment: Thank U very much ,I want to know if I should setup STATICFILES_DIRS[ ] and TEMPLATES[{''DIRS[ ]}], when I use it

Comment: Setting `STATICFILES_DIRS` isn't going to help fix a missing template. The template should be in the `django_tables2` app dir, so you shouldn't have to set `DIRS` to make it work.

Comment: If you have installed django tables 2 as an egg (not recommended), you'll have to either copy the missing template into one of your template directories (and set `DIRS`), or enable the egg loader.

Comment: yes, I have used  pip install django_tables2 and also downloaded it from github to setup, when I checked "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages", I  can see "django_tables2-1.10.0-py2.7.egg", I want to know if this installed has some problems?

Comment: I copy out "django_tables2" form "django_tables2-1.10.0-py2.7.egg"  to site-packages, it worked,but it can't load Css, is this have some problems?

Comment: "It can't load Css" isn't enough information for me to help you.

Comment: thank you all the same ,I will try it and find the problems